# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT when trying to get data from MongoDb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodemon

Im trying to use the info that i have in my database from mongo to train an IA to predict some parameters but when i try to get the data my nodemon server crashes with the error
"node:internal/errors:490
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

```
const model = require('../models/ia.js');

exports.getData= async (req,res)=>{
    // res.send( { data:"this come from ia" } ); test
    // model.find({},(err,docs)=>{
    //     res.send({
    //         docs
    //     })
    // }) apparently, that should work but mongoose does not longer admit using callbacks
    //then i do this:
    const llamadaDatos = await model.find({});
    res.send('Mis datos son: '+ llamadaDatos);
    res.send(llamadaDatos);
    console.log(llamadaDatos);
    return;
}
```

I need to return the data from the mongodb Database so i can use it to train my IA. Im good with the training part, but i cant get the data i want to.

Comment: I don't think this problem has anything to do with MongoDB. Why do you have two separate calls to `res.send()`? What happens if you remove one?